# How to add a layout to a widget, then add widget to main window

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt

I'm new to pyQt and am a bit stuck of how the layouts and widgets work. My understanding is that I need to create a new widget, then add a layout (e.g. GridLayout) to this widget and then set this layout onto the main window. The below is not working as I had hoped and I'm not sure where to go from here:

```
self.grid_widget = QtGui.QWidget(self)
self.grid_widget.setGeometry(120,10,500,235)
gridPalette = self.grid_widget.palette()
gridPalette.setColor(self.grid_widget.backgroundRole(), QtGui.QColor('white'))
self.grid_widget.setPalette(gridPalette)

grid = QtGui.QGridLayout()
self.grid_widget.setLayout(grid)            
self.setLayout(self.grid_widget)
```

I basically need the widget to be in a certain place (where I've set geometry). I could just add the grid to the window but then the grid covers the entire window and not  where I want it to be placed.

If anyone could explain the pipeline for this that would be extremely handy!

Answer (score 1):

In PyQT you usually start with a "main window". I usually make a subclass of `QtGui.QMainWindow` for that purpose. The object instantiated from that class is my "main window".
Next I make a subclass of `QtGui.QWidget`. I make an object from that class, call it my "main widget", and put it central in the "main window". Assign a layout to that "main widget" and you can start adding child widgets to it. The layout makes sure that the child widgets are well aligned.
So it is somewhat like this:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui
from PyQt4 import QtCore
import sys

class CustomMainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(CustomMainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 800, 800)
        self.setWindowTitle("my first window")

        self.mainWidget = CustomMainWidget(self) 
        self.setCentralWidget(self.mainWidget) 
        ...
        self.show()

''' End Class '''

class CustomMainWidget(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(CustomMainWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.mainLayout = None
        self.initLayout()
        self.putSomeWidgetInTheLayout()
        ...
    def initLayout(self):
        # When you use a layout, you do not need to pass a parent when
        # constructing the child widgets. The layout will automatically
        # reparent the widgets (using QWidget::setParent()) so that they
        # are children of the widget on which the layout is installed.
        # Widgets can only have other widgets as parent, not layouts.
        self.mainLayout = QtGui.QGridLayout()
        self.setLayout(self.mainLayout)

    def putSomeWidgetInTheLayout(self):
        # Notice that I don't assign a parent to 'lbl1'!
        lbl1 = QtGui.QLabel("My label")
        setCustomSize(lbl1, 160, 40)
        self.mainLayout.addWidget(lbl1, *(0,0))
        # -> I just added the label widget to the layout
        # of the main (central) widget. The label widget
        # had no parent widget to begin with. But by adding
        # it to the layout, the layout will 'reparent' the
        # label widget. So from now on, the label widget is
        # a child of the 'main (central) widget'.

        lbl2 = QtGui.QLabel("My second label")
        setCustomSize(lbl2, 160, 40)
        self.mainLayout.addWidget(lbl2, *(0,1))

''' End Class '''

def setCustomSize(x, width, height):
    sizePolicy = QtGui.QSizePolicy(QtGui.QSizePolicy.Fixed, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
    sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
    sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
    sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(x.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
    x.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
    x.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(width, height))
    x.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(width, height))

if __name__== '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myWindow = CustomMainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I hope this was helpful.
If you still have any questions, I would be happy to help you out.

Answer (score 0):

[So I used QT Designer to create a simple grid. This code is in C++ but you can easily translate it to Python. It's pretty good as it explains how the QT pipeline works, so if anyone like me has the same problems then this code should help you understand it a bit more.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WDyhX.png)